# Why can Netbeans not see a library that is clearly defined and present?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

I am working with a NetBeans project that has multiple packages. I will call them package_cam, package_demo, and package_drive. Inside of package_drive I have a class that requires a face recognition SDK that is a JAR and is clearly loaded in my libraries. However, when I run this file, I receive an unsatisfied link error stating that the sdk jar cannot be found. As I stated before, it is listed in my libraries and exists in my lib folder in the project folders. I have searched high and low in Netbeans trying to find a location where that lib must be specified but have come up short. Has anyone ever run into this before? Is there a reason that a certain package would not be able to see or use the library? I am importing the sdk at the head of the file with this

```
import Luxand.*;
import Luxand.FSDK.*;
import Luxand.FSDKCam.*;
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you use Netbeans 8 from the question tag, and your project is Ant-based)

In general the recommended way is to use a library wrapper module. There is a wizard so it's very easy,  menu File > New Project > NetBeans Modules > Library Wrapper Module. More details in these Netbeans FAQ entries: http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWhenUseWrapperModule and http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWrapperModules

If you don't use a wrapper module, you should update project.xml to add the library to the class path, for example:

```
<class-path-extension>
    <runtime-relative-path>ext/hexedit.jar</runtime-relative-path>          
    <binary-origin>release/modules/ext/hexedit.jar</binary-origin>
</class-path-extension>
```

See this other FAQ entry: http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqHowPackageLibraries